# PowerShell cast to void and return value

Tags: powershell, null, void

I have a function that is running some code and return $True in case of success and $False otherwise.

As part of the function code I cast results of some cmdlets to [void] using this

```
function New-SampleFunction
{
    [void]::('2');

     return $true
}

[bool]$myReturnValuen = New-SampleFunction

# This results in exception
The above will result in a Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
```

Of course if I let PowerShell infer the type in function return value this will work but the funny part is what I get examining the variable

```
function New-SampleFunction
{
    [void]::('2')

     return $true
}

$myReturnValuen = New-SampleFunction


$returnValue.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

But if I run $returnValue to Get-Member what I get is this

```
$returnValue | Get-Member


TypeName: System.Boolean
```

Issue is easily solved changing the above code to

```
function New-SampleFunction
{
    [void]('2')

     return $true
}

$myReturnValuen = New-SampleFunction
```

Issue in the code is resolved but I am now curious on why this behaving like this, I am of course missing something on the difference between the two void and [void]::(blahblah) and could not find any obvious answer to this.

Probaly is something really silly that I'm overlooking (had a really rough week...) but would really appreciate if somebody could enlightening me.

Thanks!

Comment: The alternative is to use `'2' | Out-Null`

Comment: Thanks @KarthickGanesan I am aware of out-null but avoid that for performance reasons.

Comment: Remember PowerShell functions return **all** output [about_return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-5.1), as @Lee_Dailey points out, you do not cast but invoke the `::` static member operator, so you do return an array.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yep I have reproduced this and makes sense, would you be able to share some more details on what is really going on under the hood here? I'm still missing the details and would be curious to know mroe.

Comment: @LotPings thanks this answer my previous question to Lee_dailey. Now it's clear and thinking about it I finally "see the light".

Full disclouse the [void]:: form is coming from a snipper in my editor... guess (abuse) intellisense obfuscated my ability to digest/elaborate "issues" like this.

Comment: In general, the standard PowerShell display output doesn't reveal all the details of an object, cmdlets like [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) `$returnValuen` and [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression/) `$returnValuen` are more enlightening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest form to suppress a return value it to **use `$null = ...`**:

```
$null = 2
```

Other, in most cases less desirable options include `2 >$null`, `2 | Out-Null`, `[void] (2)`<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `[void]::('2')`

**tries to access a *static member* (`::`) of type `[void]` named `2`**, which is the name that expression `('2')` evaluates to - which is clearly not your intent.

Since the `[void]` type has no such static member (property or method), `$null` is effectively returned<sup>[2]</sup> - and `$null` *does* get output to the pipeline, so your function has *2* outputs, `$null` and `$true`.

If you capture that in a variable, you'll get a 2-element `[object[]]` array - `$null, $true` - which explains your symptom.

---

<sup>[1] Interestingly, trying to use `[void] (...)`, as part of an *expression* causes an *error* in *Windows PowerShell* generates an *error*  in *Windows PowerShell*  (e.g., `([void] 1), 2`), whereas in PowerShell *Core* it is now more sensibly treated as `$null` (verify with `$null -eq (([void] 1), 2)[0]`).</sup>

<sup>[2]</sup>
Note that **you can prevent such inadvertent method / property references by calling `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher**.
You would then get the following statement-terminating error:

`The property '2' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.`